# FB.UI publish.stream - Not working in mobile and tabs

Tags: jquery, css, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using two versions for my website.

```
FB.ui(publish, resfunction);
```

The url is common to both mobile and desktop version.
I detect the mobile device and then simply apply the mobile themes for mobile users.
The script and layout is different for mobile users.

For desktop and laptop users, I have different theme.

1. FB.ui is working good in DESKTOP (iframe)
2. FB.ui is working good in Mobile - I use redirect method.
3. Now tab users are using the desktop version of website, where FB.ui is just showing a loading icon and does nothing.

Do i need to create another layout for tab users?
Or is it possible to make it work in tab with some css fix?